# "virtual" method with templates

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following base class :

```
template <template<class Type> class T2>
class FundamentalClass {
    typename T2<double> *_compose1;
    typename T2<int> *_compose2;

protected:
    FundamentalClass(); // Insert constructors here.

    template<class Strategy>
    T2<typename Strategy::Type> *Construct(void);

public:
    template <class Strategy>
    T2<typename Strategy::Type> *GetComposedObject(void);

};
```

with

```
template< template<class Type> class T2>
template<>
T2<double> *FundamentalClass<T2<double> >::GetComposedObject<DoubleStrategy>(void) {
    if( NULL == _compose1) {
        _compose1 = Construct<DoubleStrategy>(void);
    }
    return _compose1;
}
```

And other specializations for each composed object.

But, i need construct to be implemented by the derived class. Without templates, Construct whould be virtual. How can i achieve this goal ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with compile-time polymorphism, via the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp):

```
template <template<class Type> class T2, class Derived>
class FundamentalClass {
    ...

    template<class Strategy>
    T2<typename Strategy::Type> *Construct() {
        return static_cast<Derived *>(this)->DoConstruct<Strategy>();
    }
```

And in `Derived`, write:

```
template <template<class Type> class T2>
class Derived: public FundamentalClass<T2, Derived<T2> >
{
public:
    template<class Strategy>
    T2<typename Strategy::Type> *DoConstruct() {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I know i could go this way, but i don't like it much, since the base class has to know about the derived class...

Comment: @Enjolras the base class has to know about the derived class, either at compile time or run time; that means CRTP of virtual methods.

Comment: @Enjolras The base class only knows about the derived class's interface, not its implementation.